# Networkx degree method didn't produce want I think it is

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, networkx

I ran the following script:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 1, weight=2)
G.add_edge(1, 3, weight=2)
G.add_edge(1, 4, weight=1)
G.add_edge(1, 5, weight=5)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=3)
G.add_edge(2, 4, weight=2)
G.add_edge(3, 5, weight=4)

d = G.degree(1)

print G.edge[1]
print "Degree of node 1:", \
    G.degree(1)
print "Weighted degree of node 1:", \
    G.degree(1, weight='weight')

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
{1: {'weight': 2}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 1}, 5: {'weight': 5}}
Weighted degree: 5
Weighted degree: 12
```

And the drawing is like this:

[image: degree of the graph]

**What confused me is:**

Since there are **4** nodes adjacent to the **node 1** (including itself), why the degree is **5**?

Since the total weight of the adjacent edges of **node 1** is **10** (2+2+1+5), why the degree method produced **12**?

Thanks

Comment: Possible explanation: Your code is including the `2` number node. That is also why your total weight is 2 larger than expected

Comment: @sshashank124 Hi, I've tried removing the node2, and the question remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For an undirected graph, the degree of a vertex is equal to the number
>   of adjacent vertices.

A special case is a **loop**, which adds **two** to the degree. This can be understood by letting each connection of the loop edge count as its own adjacent vertex. In other words, a vertex with a loop "sees" itself as an adjacent vertex from both ends of the edge thus adding two, not one, to the degree.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [definition of degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29),

> In graph theory, the degree (or valency) of a vertex of a graph is the
>   number of edges incident to the vertex, *with loops counted twice*. (my emphasis)

So `G.degree(1)` is 5 since the loop from 1 to 1 is counted twice. The weighted degree also counts the loop twice, hence the total is 12 not 10, since the 1 node has weight 2.

Comment: Thank you for you thoughtful answer :)